# Does Ms Access contain the geographic information type

Tags: ms-access

Does Ms Access contain the geographic information type as Oracle, SQL Server for Arcgis, Qgis uses ?

Comment: It appears your Google is broken. The very first hit on a Google search for `ms access data types` found [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The [second](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-30ad644f-946c-442e-8bd2-be067361987c) contains more details. Does that help?

Comment: hh, No maybe I found many détails but my professor says yes it's exist so he makes me confused so that I tried to discuss it.
Another thing I've already seen some polygones as a MAP on Arcgis from Access database believe me. Maybe I could share a picture later

Answer (score 1):

> Does Ms Access contain the geographic information type

No, Access does not have a data type similar to [geography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) in SQL Server. You can store geographic information in an Access database, but only in the standard column types (e.g., lat/lon in separate numeric columns).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to store geographic information in Microsoft Access I recommend that you investigate using a [Personal Geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n00000007000000).

For [questions about Personal Geodatabases](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-geodatabase) I recommend posting to the [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com).